# MYSQL Select 5 records from one table based on several different values from another

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group, ranking

I am by no means fluent in MYSQL.  What I am trying to do is I have a table that has a list of Galleries with unique ID numbers.  I have another table ImageData that has images that may be as many as 1000 that are related to each GalleryID that is in the first table.  I want to do a select that will get 5 random records from each GalleryID.  I am trying to do this without doing a loop and multiple hits to the database.

The tables are as follows
Galleries -> GalleryID
          -> GalleryName

ImageData -> ImageID
          -> ImageName
          -> GalleryID

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What datatypes are your ID's and if they are numeric, are they something like Identity / sequences?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Randy welcome to the club. Here is a simple and fast solution to your scenario.  Enjoy

select g.GalleryName, i.imageName from Galleries g, imageData i, (SELECT gl.Galleryid from Galleries gl
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5) m where m.galleryID = i.galleryID

Comment: That wouldn't work--a sub select can only return one row of data; you're trying to put upwards of five.